# Exporting .net framework dll along with the imported dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am trying to develop a dll based on the .net framework. The single dll file generated without any imported NuGet packages works normally. But, if I try to use the imported Nuget package MathNet.Numerics, the dll fails to work on the third party application. Are there special techniques to export imported dll files along with the own dll?

Comment: you can try the nuget package: Fody.Costura. It embedds all referenced assemblies as resources.  PM> Install-Package Fody
PM> Install-Package Costura.Fody

Comment: Hi, I tried to install Fody and Costura.Fody. I was able to install Fody quite easily but I am getting following error when trying to install Install failed. 
"Rolling back...
Package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0' does not exist in project 'MembraneContactorExtn'"

Comment: When I tried to install System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0, I get the following error.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0' does not exist in project 'MembraneContactorExtn'
Package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0' does not exist in folder '\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 286 ms
Install-Package : Could not find a part of the path '\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0\lib/net45/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'.

Comment: found this: https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/301 where it is suggested you probably have a file name length issue or are using the wrong version number for your project. Try the lowest version for your target framework and if that works you could go up step by step untill it breaks then revert one.

Comment: Thanks, T.Schwarz, I was able to both export the DLL and make it work on my third-party application. It seems that the folder was inside numerous subfolders and was not able to install Fody.Costura. Thanks once again.